# Can I connect many on-prem sites to the same virtual network in Azure?

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

Here's a scenario:

I have two branches in my company. One in Toronto, the other in Montreal. I have an Azure virtual network containing a variety of resources. I want to connect both of my branches to the Azure virtual network via Site-to-Site VPN connections. My existing routers only support static routing, and I can't afford to buy new routers that support dynamic routing.

Here's the question: Is it possible to connect both my branches to the VNET in Azure without buying new equipment?

Comment: How do you expect to communicate with Azure without using the Internet?  I'm not sure why you think you need new equipment to access the VM?  How exactly/In what ways do you want to access it? Are you trying to integrate AD between both branches and your Azure virtual network?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have updated the question to better reflect what I am trying to achieve

Comment: This is very much a Server Fault question, but have you read through [the documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-site-to-site-cross-premises-connectivity/)?  If so, do you have any specific questions about it?  (those docs say site-to-site connections are supported with static routing)

Comment: @heavyd I am wondering about whether I can connect my two branches both to Azure VNET at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Azure offers a site-to-site VPN connector for connecting your Azure virtual network to your corporate network via a VPN.

> A site-to-site VPN allows you to create a secure connection between your on-premises site and your virtual network. To create a site-to-site connection, a VPN device that is located on your on-premises network is configured to create a secure connection with the Azure Virtual Network Gateway.

They provide documentation here: [Configure a Site-to-Site VPN in the Management Portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133795.aspx), and here: [Create a Cross-Premises Virtual Network for Site-to-Site Connectivity](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-site-to-site-cross-premises-connectivity/)

You will need a compatible VPN solution to act as the VPN end-point at the office(s).

Also see this MS article: [About Secure Cross-Premises Connectivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133798.aspx)

Comment: Does this allow the two branches to both connect to the VNET at the same time?

Comment: Depends on how they are currently interconnected (if at all). If they are two stand-alone networks then you'll need 2 VPN connecitons, one for each branch.

Comment: Let's assume they are not interconnected at all. Will I need dynamic routing equipment at any location?

Comment: Assuming simple networks at the branches and that you're not triyn got interconnect those two branches via the Azure vnet, then if you use the branch's central router as your VPN end-point then you should have to set up 0 additional routing, as the router will know when to send it across the VPN.  Once it's setup it works just like any other VPN, if you're not familiar with how VPNs work, then I'd start investigating that first.